# How to enable AirPrint on iPod Touch after iOS 4.2 Upgrade?

Tags: ipod-touch, airprint

I have an iPod Touch (Model MC086FD) and upgraded to iOS 4.2.1 - all works fine. But I do not find the AirPrint Software on the iPod. Can I install it? How do I make my iPod print (emails etc.) when connected by WLAN?

I have a MacBook Pro with 10.6.6 Syncing with the iPod using iTunes 10.2.1. The printer is a Samsung CLX-3175FN connected by network.

I have no Print button in the share menu. Also I tried [AirPrint Activator](http://netputing.com/airprintactivator/) to enable for my network printer. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My iPod touch is an 3. generation 8GB model (Model [MC086FD](http://www.everyipod.com/ipod-faq/ipod-nano-mini-shuffle-apple-model-numbers.html)).  As I found, [Multitasking](http://www.tipb.com/2010/09/15/ios-42-airprint-iphone-3g/) is needed to use AirPrint! But multitasking is [not available](http://techie-buzz.com/mobile-news/how-to-multitask-in-ios4-on-iphone-ipod-touch.html) for this model - even iOS 4.2 installed!

Answer (score 1):

AirPrint doesn't require an extra App. It works directly from the `print`-menu, if your printer has support for the feature.

Here's a list of supported printer's and other notes for AirPrint:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4356

Comment: there is no print menu!

Comment: Excuse me? What are you trying to print?  One example, go to `Photos > Select an album > Select a photo > Push the leftmost button on the bottom (square wit arrow coming out) > Select Print`

Comment: There is no print, just email, contact and background!

Comment: Are you on WiFi?

Comment: I don't think that all apps support airprint, what app are you using? I can check if it works on mine or not as I have it set up and have printed before.

Comment: BTW your printer is not on the list of supported devices...

Comment: @deiga: Yes, Wifi with Same Network As Printer and Sharing macbook

Comment: @Arne - What app are you using, like TheX already asked? There is no sense that this menu doesn't show up :D

Comment: I have tried Mail, Photos and Safari - none of them has a print button!

Comment: @Arne - That really makes to sense :D In what country are you? Have you tried reinstalling your iOS?

Comment: @deiga: I am in germany. No, I have not reinstalled iOS, how to?

Comment: @Arne - Plug your iPhone to your computer, then in iTunes, on the first page there is a button 'Restore'. Remember that this erases all data from the phone.

Comment: Did a restore, but nothing changes - no print button

Comment: OK, can you go into photos, open up a Photo an then open the menu from the leftmost button? Then take a screenshot of this. You take screenshots by keeping the home button pressed and then pressing the power button, the screen should flash.